# How to connect to socket after login - JWT

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, jwt

I am using socketio-jwt to authenticate sockets.

On the server:

```
socketio.use(require('socketio-jwt').authorize({
  secret: config.secrets.session,
  handshake: true
}));
```

On the client:

```
var ioSocket = io('', {
  query: 'token=' + Auth.getToken(),
  path: '/socket.io-client'
});
```

My problem is, that if a client is connecting to the server, the authentication fails, and no connection to with the socket is established. Now if the user logs into the system, the connection with the socket is remains not established.

What I try to achieve is, that if a user logs into the system, the connection gets established.

My only idea so far is to reload the page with something like `$window.location.href = '/';` after login. But it seems like not the proper way.

Another option would be to keep the socket trying to (re)connect with a timeout. But its a bad option, since my application allows users without login.

How to properly trigger a socket connection?

Comment: Why not trigger the connection once the user has logged in?

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the solution to your problem

Firstly on your **server side** you can implement and bind the user credentials to a `token` as shown below.

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
app.post('/loginpage',function(req,res){
 //validate the user here

});

//generate the token of the user based upon the credentials

var server = //create the http server here.
```

In the **socket.io** server side you can do the following

```
  //require socket.io
  var xxx = socketIo.listen //to the server
  xxx.set('auth',socketIojwtauthorize({
    secret: config.secrets.session,
    handshake: true
    }));
   xxx.sockets //here connection on or off by setting up promise

   //server listen to localhost and port of your choice
```

When the `client` sends a valid `jwt` connection is triggered

Simple **client side** file would contain the following `modules`

```
//function connectsocket(token){
      //connect(
      //and query the token );
  }
//socket.on('connect',function(){
  //generate the success message here
  }).on('disconnect',function(){ //your choice })
  //rendering the routes with the server side
  $.post('/loginroute',{
  //user credentials passes here 
  }).done(function(bind){ connect_socket(  bind.token )})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var socket = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socket.listen(server);
io.on('connection', function (client) {
 // here server side code
})
server.listen(5000);

on client side include
node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js
socket = io.connect(site_url + ":5000", {        reconnect: !0    });
```

Comment: Is there a special reason why use `!0`? Why not just `1` or `true`?